# Guided proof on Schröder - Bernstein theorem

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is a past exam exercise I'm struggling to solve: I was able to proove $Q\cup f[\mathcal{T}]\subseteq \mathcal{T}$ and had no luck afterwards.

We have:

1. $A'\subseteq B \subseteq A$ such that $A=_c A'$
2. $f:A \rightarrow A'$ an isomorphism.
3. $Q=B / f[A]$
4. $\mathcal{T}=\left\{X\subseteq A| Q\cup f[X]\subseteq X\right\}$  and  $T=\bigcap_{X\in \mathcal{T}}X$.

I would like to prove the following:

1. $Q\cup f[T]=T$

Any hints on the $T\subseteq Q \cup f[T]$?

Thank you in advance for your time and effort. This is part of a guided proof of Schröder-Bernstein Theorem.

Comment: What $B/f[A]$ means?

Comment: $B-f[A]$ which since $f$ is an isomorphism equals to $B-A'$.

Comment: Brian M. Scott once gave a complete proof of the Cantor-Bernstein theorem on this site. I find that giving elaborated proofs for a theorem (whose proof is not very short) that you can find in many books, websites and notes is by definition very broad. Please restrict to a single point which you don't understand in the process of the proof, and I will retract my vote to close/vote to reopen. As it stands, the question is too broad.

Comment: By the way... nice title on your webpage. Although I thought you set theorists always have a choice!

Comment: Any hints on the first 3 questions is more than enough. If someone knows a similar proof of the theorem that would also be great.

Comment: @Asaf: Complete proof [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/345202/12042), and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/225635/12042) with diagrams.

Comment: Formal proof (in excruciating detail) at http://dcproof.com/CBS.htm and http://dcproof.com/KnasterFPL.htm

Comment: Thank you all very much for helping out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $f[T]\subseteq T$, so $f[f[T]]\subseteq f[T]$. We also have $Q\subseteq T$ and therefore $f[Q]\subseteq f[T]$, so $f[Q\cup f[T]]\subseteq Q\cup f[T]$, and hence $Q\cup f[T]\in\mathscr{T}$. The desired inclusion now follows immediately.

Comment: Is it me, or are you proving the other direction than the requested hint?

Comment: Yes but that shows that $ Q \cup f[T] \subseteq T$ which is the part I've proven. What was hard (for me at least) is to prove $T\subseteq Q\cup f[T]$.

Comment: @epsilon: Argh! You're right, of course, though I could have sworn that I double-checked the direction. I'll fix it in a few minutes.

Comment: Thank you! It's all clear to me now.

Comment: @epsilon: You’re welcome!